# JPA access Postgresql 9.4 generated sequence "id" not exist error

Tags: postgresql, jpa, position, sequence, identity-column

I had a project needs to set up SMS gateway that works with JAVA-EE project. GAMMU 1.36.0 was selected.

backend DB is Postgresql 9.4, table inbox and sequence were created to hold in come SMS.

inbox created by use:

```
CREATE TABLE inbox (
"UpdatedInDB" timestamp(0) WITHOUT time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT     LOCALTIMESTAMP(0),
"ReceivingDateTime" timestamp(0) WITHOUT time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT LOCALTIMESTAMP(0),
"Text" text NOT NULL,
"SenderNumber" varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
"Coding" varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Default_No_Compression',
"UDH" text NOT NULL,
"SMSCNumber" varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
"Class" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
"TextDecoded" text NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
"ID" serial PRIMARY KEY,
"RecipientID" text NOT NULL,
"Processed" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT 'false',
CHECK ("Coding" IN 
  ('Default_No_Compression','Unicode_No_Compression','8bit','Default_Compression','Unicode_Compression')));
```

id is a sequence number hold in:

```
--CREATE SEQUENCE inbox_ID_seq;
```

table structure looks like:

```
smsd-> \d inbox
                                            Table "public.inbox"
  Column       |              Type              |                           Modifiers                            
-------------------+--------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
UpdatedInDB       | timestamp(0) without time zone | not null default ('now'::text)::timestamp(0) without time zone
ReceivingDateTime | timestamp(0) without time zone | not null default ('now'::text)::timestamp(0) without time zone
Text              | text                           | not null
SenderNumber      | character varying(20)          | not null default ''::character varying
Coding            | character varying(255)         | not null default 'Default_No_Compression'::character varying
UDH               | text                           | not null
SMSCNumber        | character varying(20)          | not null default ''::character varying
Class             | integer                        | not null default (-1)
TextDecoded       | text                           | not null default ''::text
ID                | integer                        | not null default nextval('"inbox_ID_seq"'::regclass)
RecipientID       | text                           | not null
Processed         | boolean                        | not null default false
Indexes:
"inbox_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("ID")
Check constraints:
"inbox_Coding_check" CHECK ("Coding"::text = ANY (ARRAY['Default_No_Compression'::character varying, 'Unicode_No_Compression'::character varying, '8bit'::character varying, 'Default_Compression'::character varying, 'Unicode_Compression'::character varying]::text[]))
Triggers:
update_timestamp BEFORE UPDATE ON inbox FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_timestamp()

smsd->
```

Please note: column ids' position is 10 in the table.

This table is working well with GAMMU 1.36.0, send and receive SMS properly.

When I try to develop a EJB to bring the inbox information to my web application.

I am using JPA 2.1, implementation is EclipseLink 2.5.2. persistence.xml looks like:

```
<persistence-unit name="SmsdJPANBPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
       <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <mapping-file>com/longz/smsd/model/SmsdInboxEntity.xml</mapping-file>
    <mapping-file>com/longz/smsd/model/SmsdOutboxEntity.xml</mapping-file>
    <mapping-file>com/longz/smsd/model/SmsdSentitemsEntity.xml</mapping-file>
    <class>com.longz.smsd.model.SmsdInboxEntity</class>
    <class>com.longz.smsd.model.SmsdOutboxEntity</class>
    <class>com.longz.smsd.model.SmsdSentitemsEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://10.0.1.100:5433/smsd"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.user" value="any"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.password" value="any"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

JPA entity bean defined:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "inbox", schema = "public", catalog = "smsd")
@NamedQueries({
    /*@NamedQuery(name = "Inbox.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM InboxEntity i ORDER BY i.id DESC"),*/
    @NamedQuery(name = "Inbox.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM SmsdInboxEntity i order by i.id desc"),
......
public class SmsdInboxEntity implements Serializable{
......
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="JOB_MISFIRE_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="inbox_ID_seq",schema = "public", allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="JOB_MISFIRE_ID_GENERATOR")
@Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
......
}
```

stateless session bean as:

```
@Remote(InboxEntityFacadeRemote.class)
@Stateless(mappedName= "inboxEntityFacadeEJB")
public class InboxEntityFacade extends AbstractFacade<SmsdInboxEntity> implements InboxEntityFacadeRemote {
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "SmsdJPANBPU")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

public InboxEntityFacade() {
    super(SmsdInboxEntity.class);
}
@Override
public List<SmsdInboxEntity> findAll(){
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Inbox.findAll");
    return new LinkedList<SmsdInboxEntity>(query.getResultList());
    /*return super.findAll();*/
}
```

I tried to use findall() function to list all sms in inbox. This function will call named query statement:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Inbox.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM SmsdInboxEntity i order by i.id desc"),
```

Test EJB client as:

```
try {
        Context context = new InitialContext(properties);
        InboxEntityFacadeRemote inboxEnFaRemote = (InboxEntityFacadeRemote)context.lookup("inboxEntityFacadeEJB#com.longz.smsd.remote.InboxEntityFacadeRemote");
        System.out.println("inboxEntityFacadeEJB found.");
        List<com.longz.smsd.model.SmsdInboxEntity> todaysemails = inboxEnFaRemote.findAll();
        System.out.println("Records found: "+ todaysemails.size());
        todaysemails.stream().forEach((e) -> {
            System.out.println(e.getTextDecoded());
        });

    }catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Everything is work fine so far. but very strange error thrown:

```
run:
inboxEntityFacadeEJB found.
Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "id" does not exist
  Position: 8
  Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT ID, Class, Coding, Processed, ReceivingDateTime, RecipientID, SenderNumber, SMSCNumber, Text, TextDecoded, UDH, UpdatedInDB FROM smsd.public.inbox ORDER BY ID DESC
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="Inbox.findAll" referenceClass=SmsdInboxEntity sql="SELECT ID, Class, Coding, Processed, ReceivingDateTime, RecipientID, SenderNumber, SMSCNumber, Text, TextDecoded, UDH, UpdatedInDB FROM smsd.public.inbox ORDER BY ID DESC")
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:117)
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:92)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.findAll(Unknown Source)
at weblogicejbclient.WeblogicInboxEJBClient.main(WeblogicInboxEJBClient.java:38)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "id" does not exist
  Position: 8
  Error Code: 0
Call: SELECT ID, Class, Coding, Processed, ReceivingDateTime, RecipientID, SenderNumber, SMSCNumber, Text, TextDecoded, UDH, UpdatedInDB FROM smsd.public.inbox ORDER BY ID DESC
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="Inbox.findAll" referenceClass=SmsdInboxEntity sql="SELECT ID, Class, Coding, Processed, ReceivingDateTime, RecipientID, SenderNumber, SMSCNumber, Text, TextDecoded, UDH, UpdatedInDB FROM smsd.public.inbox ORDER BY ID DESC")
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:378)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:260)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:469)
at com.longz.smsd.ejb.InboxEntityFacade.findAll(InboxEntityFacade.java:36)
at com.longz.smsd.ejb.InboxEntityFacadeEJB_s9wt3_InboxEntityFacadeRemoteImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:34)
at com.longz.smsd.ejb.InboxEntityFacadeEJB_s9wt3_InboxEntityFacadeRemoteImpl.findAll(Unknown Source)
at com.longz.smsd.ejb.InboxEntityFacadeEJB_s9wt3_InboxEntityFacadeRemoteImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.invoke(BasicServerRef.java:701)
at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableServerRef.invoke(ClusterableServerRef.java:231)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef$1.run(BasicServerRef.java:527)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:523)
at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "id" does not exist
  Position: 8
  Error Code: 0
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:682)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2002)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2738)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2691)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:495)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1168)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:403)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1215)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1751)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
... 15 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "id" does not exist
  Position: 8
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2198)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1927)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:561)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:419)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:304)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1007)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:642)
... 35 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

seems PSQL trying find "id" column in position 8 instead of position 10 and actually "id" column located in position 10 in inbox table.

Any idea and advice please! Appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually. This issue was fixed by using native SQL query

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("Select * from inbox",com.longz.smsd.model.SmsdInboxEntity.class);
return new LinkedList<SmsdInboxEntity>(query.getResultList());
```

Seems JSQL is not 100% works in this situation.

This one will be help some one else who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is case-sensitivity: [JPA works in case insensitive mode](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Entities/Table#Case_Sensitively.2C_Reserved_Words_and_Special_Characters) by default (i.e. it won't quote identifiers in its queries), while [PostgreSQL will convert any unquoted identifiers to lower-case](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) (this is the way PostgreSQL tries to achieve case insensitivity). But, you defined your `"ID"` column in case-sensitive mode (note the quotes).

An ugly workaround is, that you define your entity in a case-sensitive way:

```
@Column(name = "\"ID\"")
```

Or, you can define your table in a case-insensitive way (which is preferred):

```
CREATE TABLE inbox (
    ID serial PRIMARY KEY
    -- ...
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! seems this work around works for me. Unfortunately, I can't redefine the DB schema, as C++ need to use it, it has to keep it as. Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and advice. I just tested it, but it not works all the time.